# Reading excel with unicode not always correct

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, xlrd

Before I continue with my excel python program I should maybe understand my encoding issue. My problem is that some functions are giving me back unicode characters correctly and some of them not. I'm using [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) with Python 2.7.8 and here is an example:

I have an excel file with 3 sheets with the name **One**, **Two** and **Test ÄÁµ Unicode** - when using code like this the output is not correct

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Testfile.xlsx')
print "output:", workbook.sheet_names()

output: [u'One', u'Two', u'Test \xc4\xc1\xb5 Unicode']
```

When using the same function just with iteration its working well:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Testfile.xlsx')
worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()
for worksheet_name in worksheets:
  worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
  print "output:", worksheet.name

output: One
output: Two
output: Test ÄÁµ Unicode
```

This is just one example with the sheets, I managed also to find a lot of these encoding issues when reading cells and rows. Sometimes it´s ok sometimes not. At first, is this a python issue or is there something wrong with xlrd? Second, how do I ensure that encoding is always correct?

~ I was also trying to use `encoding_override` with cp1252 or unicode, but that won't change anything.

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Testfile.xlsx', encoding_override="cp1252")
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\Testfile.xlsx', encoding_override="utf-8")
```

Comment: You're just seeing the difference between the `repr` of a string and the string itself. When you print out a string contained in a list, it calls `repr` automatically.

Comment: @MarkRansom ahh! When printing the list at [2] the string is correct. Was the first time reading about repr, thank you that is gonna change a lot for me - thought I'm doing something really wrong wit unicode.